# Javascript create a list of functions dynamically

Tags: javascript, function

I have a piece of `JavaScript` code that I want to create a list of functions. All the functions will be put in a dictionary `d`. `d["a"]` will give me the function `function() {console.log("a")}` and `d["b"]` will give me the function `function() {console.log("b")}` etc. This is my code:

```
var a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890".split("");
var d = {};
for(var l = a.length, i = 0; i < l; i++)
{
    d[a[i]] = function(){console.log(a[i])};
}
```

However, when I run the above code, `d["a"]` and `d["b"]` will be the same, they all point to `function(){console.log(a[i])}`. How to get what I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give each instance of the function its own variable:

```
for(var l = a.length, i = 0; i < l; i++)
{
  (function (x) {
    d[a[x]] = function(){console.log(a[x])};
  })(i)
}
```

Comment: I got the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token (" when I run it on Chrome. Does the syntax supported by Chrome?

Comment: Enclose the outer function in brackets like this: (function(x) { ... })(i)

Comment: Sorry, yes, `function() { }()` must be `(function () {})()`.

Answer (score 0):

They don't point to the same instance of `function(){console.log(a[i])}`, instead, you've created a bunch of functions that all use the same reference to `i`. The value that `i` points at changes as the `for` loop executes.

The other answers provided will work, but it involves generating twice as many functions as you need.

```
function makeLogFunction(whatToLog) {
    return function() {
        console.log(whatToLog);
    }
}

var a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
var d = {};
for(var l = a.length, i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    d[a[i]] = makeLogFunction(a[i]);
}
```

Here, I have a `makeLogFunction` that will return a new function that always prints `whatToLog`. The other answers will generate a new "version" of the makeLogFunction every time the loop executes. For very large sets of data, this is a waste of time and memory.

This approach has added advantages of clarity and reusability. If there's a significant amount of logic happening in your loop, encapsulating it in a named function allows future reviewers to get a sense of what's going on by the name you give to the function. You can also reuse the function in other parts of your application.