# Create function dynamically Javascript CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144843/javascript-create-a-list-of-functions-dynamically), and I am trying this:

```
  for _notice in ['created', 'edited']
    ((notice) ->
      Template.test[notice] = ->
        console.log notice
        Session.get notice
    )(_notice)
```

But in console I am getting `created` twice, also:

```
> Template.test.edited
> function () {
      console.log(notice);
      return Session.get(notice);
    }
```

I suppose I want to see `edited` in function, how could I do that? or how can I define these functions using the for loop?

Comment: (1) The structure works fine, what are you doing differently than http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/L9jLN/ ? (2) Normally you'd use a `do` loop for this rather than your own SIF: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/gsPc8/

Comment: I forgot to answer the comment, as far as I see I am not doing anything different. Thanks for the `do` notation, what is SIF?

Comment: SIF == "self invoking function", i.e. `(function(x) { .. })(x)` in JavaScript or `((x) -> ...)(x)` in CoffeeScript.

Comment: Can you reproduce the behavior at jsfiddle.net, jsbin.com, or even the "TRY COFFEESCRIPT" tab at coffeescript.org?